# JavaScript getDate() not adjusting date correctly when adding and substracting

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a JavaScript function that adjusts the date when a button is clicked. It uses the getDate() function and substracts 7 days from the current date value in the textbox. The problem that I am seeing, and I have tried various ways to correct, but nothing seems to work is that when I click the button it shows the correct date, when I click it again rather going back another seven days it jumps to a completely different date - for example, if the date in the text box is 05/01/2014, I click the button it goes to 29/12/2014, I click it again, I get 28/11/2015 - NOT 22/12/2014.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
   var fromDateIn = new Date(formatDate(document.getElementById('<%= txtFromDate.ClientID%>').value));
      var newdate = new Date(fromDateIn);
      newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() - 7);
      var nd = new Date(newdate);

      document.getElementById('<%= txtFromDate.ClientID%>').value = formatDate(nd);

     function formatDate(inputDate) {

      var d = new Date(inputDate || Date.now()),
    month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
    day = '' + d.getDate(),
    year = d.getFullYear();

      if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
      if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

      return [day, month, year].join('/');

  }
```

Can someone please point out to me how I can consistently substract 7 days from whatever is the current date value in the textbox?

Thanks

Comment: In your example you have the day before the month in the input string. The date constructor wants the month to  be before the day. Maybe that's part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you're using your formatted date to construct the new `fromDateIn`

Initialize the value on load, and use the `newdate` variable to do the calculation, call the function `changeDate()` on your button click.

```
var fromDateIn = new Date(formatDate(document.getElementById('<%=txtFromDate.ClientID%>').value));
var newdate = new Date(fromDateIn);

function changeDate() 
{
   newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() - 7);
   document.getElementById('<%= txtFromDate.ClientID%>').value = formatDate(newdate);
}

function formatDate(inputDate) 
{        
   var d = new Date(inputDate || Date.now()),
   month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
   day = '' + d.getDate(),
   year = d.getFullYear();

   if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
   if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;        
   return [day, month, year].join('/');        
}
```

Comment: Hi Sorry for the delay in replying, but can you advise where in javascript I set the fromDateIn value? If I create a Init function the date value won't yet exist and the value won't be accessible to changedate?

Comment: Place the scriptblock at the end of the page, or use `window.onload` (or `$(document).ready()` if you use jQuery)